# Which Salesforce License is required to use Environment Hub?

Tags: licenses, environment-hub

**Preface: this is no duplicate**

This is not a duplicate of this question [Which Salesforce License is required to use Dev Hub (beta)?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/186621/which-salesforce-license-is-required-to-use-dev-hub-beta)

[Dev Hub](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_hub_intro.htm&ved=0ahUKEwjNxZLv9-LVAhXSYlAKHVRtA5AQFgg0MAI&usg=AFQjCNGY0rCtNSJBfP2yB9e40j4GFMLXiA) and [Environment Hub](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/general/Environment_Hub&ved=0ahUKEwjNxZLv9-LVAhXSYlAKHVRtA5AQFggyMAE&usg=AFQjCNHRQLY5eEUvUjifoxHyqA_9cKJlgQ) are two totally different things. Only the question about which license is required for using each of them can be asked for both distinct Hubs. Please don't get confused. I've carefully split up these two questions and the duplicate mark is definitely wrong.

**Original Question**

Today I've tried to enable Environment Hub for some of our Developers. Environment Hub itself is working only for me as I am using a Salesforce license with the Profile System Administrator.

Since the Devs are not involved in selling activities, we use Plattform Licenses (Force.com) for them.

Now they should be able to spin up and manage SSO for our dev orgs.

I was able to grant them access to the tab and the objects - but not for the Environment Hub App.

Is there any way to allow these licenses to use the environment hub? If not, why such an restriction? It does not make sense to provide them with a Sales Cloud License.

Comment: Within the settings for the app itself, is the app visible to those profiles? (QuickFind > Create > Apps > [Env Hub - Edit])

Comment: @Uwe Heim did you manage to get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the steps outlined in [this documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=environment_hub_get_started_configure_app.htm&type=5) (see below), you can actually get access.
However, the Environment Hub tab still won't show up in your app launcher, but you can go there by navigating to `https://YOUR_DOMAIN.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/EnvironmentHubMember/list`. Everything seems to work well from there, viewing all connected orgs as well as creating / connecting orgs.

> 1. Contact Salesforce to enable the Environment Hub in your org. If you’re an ISV partner, you can skip this step. The Environment Hub is already installed in your Partner Business Org.
> 2. Log in to the org where the Environment Hub is enabled, and then go to Setup.
> 3. Assign users access to features in the Environment Hub.
>      a. From Setup, enter Profiles in the Quick Find box, then select **Profiles**.
>      b. Create a profile, or edit an existing one.
>      c. Edit the profile’s settings.
>
> **Custom App Settings**
>   Enable the Environment Hub custom app to make it available in the App Launcher in Lightning Experience or App Menu in Salesforce Classic.
>
> **Connected App Access**
>   Unless advised by Salesforce, don’t adjust settings in this section of the profile.
>   **Service Provider Access**
>   If you enable single sign-on (SSO) in a member org, new entries appear in this section of the profile. Entries appear in the format **Service Provider [Organization ID]**, where Organization ID is the ID of the member org. Users who don’t have access to the service provider sometimes see this message when attempting to log in via SSO: “User ‘[UserID]’ does not have access to sp ‘[Service Provider ID]’.”
>   When configuring the Environment Hub in a new org, this section is empty.
>
> **Administrative Permissions**
>   Enable “Manage Environment Hub” to allow users to:
>
> - Create orgs for development, testing, and trials.
> - Configure SSO for member orgs.
>
> **General User Permissions**
>   Enable “Connect Organization to Environment Hub” to allow users to connect existing orgs to the Environment Hub.
>
> **Standard Object Permissions**
>   Grant object permissions based on the level of access required by the Environment Hub user.
>
> Hub Members object:
>
> - “Read”—View existing Hub Member records.
> - “Create”—This permission has no impact on the ability to create Hub Member records. That’s because record creation is handled either by connecting an existing org or creating an org from the Environment Hub.
> - “Edit”—Edit fields on existing Hub Member records.
> - “Delete”—Disconnect an org from the Environment Hub and delete its corresponding Hub Member record and Service Provider record (if SSO was enabled for the member).
> - “View All”—Read all Hub Member records, regardless of who created them.
> - “Modify All”—Read, edit, and delete all Hub Member records, regardless of who created them.
>
> Hub Invitations object:
>
> - If you enable the “Connect Organization to Environment Hub” permission, enable “Create”, “Read”, “Update, and “Delete” for Hub Invitations.
>
> Signup Request object:
>
> - If you enable the “Manage Environment Hub” permission, enable “Create” and “Read” for Signup Requests to allow users to create orgs. Optionally, enable “Delete” to allow users to remove orgs from the hub.
>
>   d. Select **Save**.