# Which Salesforce License is required to use Dev Hub (beta)?

Tags: licenses, dev-hub

Today I've tried to enable the new Dev Hub for some of our Developers. Dev Hub itself is working only for me as I am using a Salesforce license with the Profile System Administrator. Since the Devs are not involved in selling activities, we use Plattform Licenses (Force.com) for them.

Now the devs should be able to use the Dev Hub.

I was able to create the Permission Set as described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm).

But as I'm trying to assign the permissio set, I get only an error complaining about the license type.

Is there any way to allow these licenses to use the dev hub? If not, why such an restriction? It does not make sense to provide them with a Sales Cloud License.

Comment: The documentation suggests that a Salesforce license is required, but they don't explicitly say why. Consider asking your question over on the dx beta chatter channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce plans to bring a new License type for this come Winter 18.

https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?fId=0D53A00003Dml6e&g=0F93A000000HTp1

> We are working on providing a new type of free user license in the partner business org which will let you onboard developers in to the Dev Hub. Since the Dev Hub's primary purpose is to spin up scratch orgs, it can be shared across the different projects/customers you're working with. Alternatively, a customer can create a user for SI devs in their Dev Hub in which case you would use their scratch allocations.

Answer (score 1):

Due to [this document](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/186621/which-salesforce-license-is-required-to-use-dev-hub-beta),

> After you’ve enabled Dev Hub capabilities in an org, you’ll need to
> create user records for any members of your team who you want to allow
> to use the Dev Hub functionality, if they aren’t already Salesforce
> users. Three types of licenses work for Salesforce DX users:
> Salesforce, Salesforce Platform and the new Salesforce Limited Access
> license.

So basically it should work for

- Salesforce
- Salesforce Platform
- Salesforce Limited Access

Licenses.

Comment: Unfortunately Salesforce Platform licenses don't seem to work if you want to create packages. If you try to give users with that profile permissions to create packages, you get the error ```The user license doesn't allow the permission: Create and Update Second-Generation Packages```

Answer (score -2):

If they're working in full Salesforce Orgs, it only seems appropriate to me that they have Salesforce User licenses. It may not make sense to you, but I can understand why it would make sense to Salesforce to expect Devs to have Salesforce Licenses if they're working in a Sales Cloud org. I'd expect the same if I were working with Service Cloud, Wave, Commerce Cloud, Marketing Cloud, etc.

Comment: No, I can't follow that. They need to work on Developer Editions and the new Scratch Orgs, both free. Nothing else is involved.