# Which Salesforce License is required to use Dev Hub? (Revisited)

Tags: salesforcedx

About three years ago [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/186621/which-salesforce-license-is-required-to-use-dev-hub-beta) questions was asked.  No I have same question. I have a DX project for managed package (namespace).  The namespace is hosted in my private dev org.   I wish to onboard a new collaborator to this project and I would like to give the collaborator an account with a platform license so s/he can create namespaced scratch orgs.  Is this possible?  I've only been able to get the cli to really work with the System Administrator/Salesforce License.

Yes, I'm aware of partner orgs.  We will need to refactor to a new namespace and go this route when we ge serious about release but we're not at that stage yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For a partner**:

The Dev Hub is mandated (by Salesforce decree) to be your PBO. Doing otherwise is not supported and you won't be granted the partner-level numbers of dev hub users, active scratch orgs and daily scratch org creations otherwise.

The license type of "Salesforce Limited Access - Free" [can be requested](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_hub_license.htm) for addition to your PBO, against which you should create a Permission Set to enable the following System Permissions:

- "API Enabled"
- "Create and Update Second-Generation Packages"
- optionally "Promote a package version to released"**

**: You might do this with a second permission set, depending whether you allow all developers to promote package versions or not.

You create your developer users on your PBO/Dev Hub using a profile against this same license and add them to the permission set. (Yeah, you don't have to use a permission set, but Salesforce are heading towards killing off Profiles so you might as well start using permission sets now.)

NB: As @sfdcfox said, your namespace org doesn't need to be accessible by collaborators; you simply need to link that namespace to your Dev Hub and have collaborator access to the Dev Hub for SFDX usage.

Comment: from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm it says.  "You can use Salesforce DX with these standard user licenses: Salesforce, Salesforce Platform, and Developer. "   I'll create a permission set with the permissions above and one's listed in the link an see how it goes.   Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Note that I specifically framed this in terms of what partners do. Be aware that you cannot move a package from one dev hub to another, so you need to make sure you create your "real" packages only once you have a PBO. Any customer using your old package won't have an easy time in migrating. I believe you *might* be able to link a namespace from another dev hub but I've never tried it.

Answer (score 2):

The modern setup includes the use of the [Salesforce Developer](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_available.htm&type=5) license type (as opposed to the Salesforce CRM licenses that normal users use) and setting the Permission Set described in [Add Salesforce DX Users](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm). Note that the "Platform License" is not appropriate here. That's not the correct license for developers.

Also note that the expected Salesforce DX life cycle is the use of [Second Generation Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp.htm) (2GMP), in which *nobody* logs in to the Developer Edition org; this org is used only to maintain the namespace, and the Dev Hub org is where your developer user accounts should be hosted (this is typically a Production Org). The Developer License type does not allow any CRM access, custom object access, or AppExchange access. It is used solely to develop 2GMP.

Comment: Thank you!   Neither of our configured dev hubs have 'Salesforce Developer' licenses.   So right now the Salesforce License looks like the correct choice until the project justifies purchase of a pattern org.    We are using 2GMP BTW for our newer manger packages.

Comment: Hello @sfdcfox, do you happen to know if the Salesforce Developer is a paid license? I have seen this license on docs but could not yet figure out if there is a cost involved. I have also not seen this on any org so far.

Comment: @JefersonChaves It is my understanding that this license type only exists in paid orgs of at least Enterprise Edition, and it is provided at no cost. You may need to contact Sales or Support to have this enabled, but new orgs should have this license type automatically.